# Don't understand why there are downvotes for my question

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I asked this question here: [Expected number of rounds in dice game for player who wins](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602180/expected-number-of-rounds-in-dice-game-for-player-who-wins)

And it already has $2$ downvotes. Why? My probability professor didn't know, and I even showed my work in describing my thoughts.

Comment: There are some comments to your question and if some clarification is sought you may update your post by adding more details. That may help you to some extent.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C130.1682)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: You remark above that you asked your probability professor and that person did not know.  I would be more receptive to your Question if you went into more detail about the origin of the problem and its motivation.  For example did you see a similar problem solved using Markov chains? Is that approach one you were taught? Our goal is to (1) help you learn (even if it involves going beyond the borders of your probability class) and (2) to leave great content for future Readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major problem that I see with your question is that the title asks one thing ("Expected number of rounds in dice game for player who wins") while the body asks another ("How many points per round on average does the winning player earn?"). Is this a good reason for downvoting? No. Some people are quick to downvote, like others are quick to curse. Not your fault. Put the title in agreement with the body and move on.